# How can I define variable constants based on user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some help in basic Python. I have 3 files.  constant.py, main.py, function.py

In constant.py, I want

```
if input == "opt1":
    A = 10
elif input == "opt2":
    A = 20
```

In main.py,

```
from constant import A
input = sys.argv[1]
B = A + 10
```

In functions.py

```
from constant import A
C = A + 20
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: Shouldn't `input = sys.argv[1]` be in `constant.py`?

Comment: That seems to be the problem OP wants to solve: affecting the result of the `import`, according to locally defined quantities.

Comment: Note: Don't use `input` as a variable name, because it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the built-in [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function.